# phpmailer file attachment delivered, but downloads a string only

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a dxf file saved in my `public_html` folder on my server. I would like to add this as an attachment to an email. I apply the following code line:

`$mail->AddStringAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myDxf.dxf', 'myFile.dxf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');`

This attaches a dxf and the email is sent. However, when I download the attachment, instead of being a true dxf, it just has a string inside with the file path:

```
/home3/frank/public_html/myDxf.dxf
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two places to start troubleshooting:

**1. Attaching of File**

Instead of this:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment()
```

try this:

```
$mail->AddAttachment()
```

> [File Attachments](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)
>
> The command to attach a local file is simply
>   `$mail->addAttachment($path);`, where `$path` contains the path to the
>   file you want to send, and can be placed anywhere between `$mail = new PHPMailer;` and sending the message. Note that *you cannot use a URL
>   for the path* - you may only use local filesystem path.
>
> If you want to send content from a database or web API (e.g. a remote PDF generator), do not use this method - use `addStringAttachment` instead.

---

**2. MIME type**

Instead of this:

```
application/pdf
```

try this:

```
image/vnd.dxf
```

List of MIME types: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html